# Is there an alternative to cv2.resize() in OpenCV for downscaling images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I'm using OpenCV with Python to process images for AI training. I need to scale the images down to 32×32 pixels, but with `cv2.resize()` the images come out too noisy. It looks like this function takes the value of a single pixel from each region of the image, but I need an average value of each region so that the images are less noisy. Is there an alternative to `cv2.resize()`? I could just write my own function but I don't think it would be very fast.

Comment: Use cv2.INTER_AREA in cv2.resize

Comment: cv2.INTER_AREA processes blocks of pixels. The blocks are the size needed to reduce the image size. So it is an average of the pixels in each block that are assigned to the output image. The result should be better for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [**`cv2.resize`** documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d), the last parameter `interpolation` determines the way the image is resampled.
See also the [possible values for it](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

The default is **`cv2.INTER_LINEAR`** meaning a linear interpolation. It can create a blurred/noisy effect when the image is downsampled.

You can try to use other interpolation methods to see if the result is better suited for your needs.
Sepcifically I recommend you to try the **`cv2.INTER_NEAREST`** option. It will determine the destination pixel value based on the color of the nearest pixel in the source. The downsampled image should be pixellated, but not blurred.
Another option is **`cv2.INTER_AREA`** as mentioned in [@fmw42's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156182/is-there-an-alternative-to-cv2-resize-in-opencv-for-downscaling-images/73156311#comment129203262_73156182).